# OpenCv Python: How to save name of the recognized face from face recognition program after the face is recognised?

Tags: python, opencv

Hi everyone I'm working on OpenCV(Python)on a face recognition program. I have two files, one which captures a new user's face and stores it by the name supplied by user. The second file recognizes the user using webcam. Now, my concern is that the user is getting recognised correctly but the name is only shown and not saved. How could I save the name of the recognised person so that it can be transfered or done some operations upon?

```
#__author__ = 'ADMIN'
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
size = 4
fn_haar = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
fn_dir = 'att_faces'
fn_name = "aditya"
path = os.path.join(fn_dir, fn_name)
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
(im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)
haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fn_haar)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# The program loops until it has 20 images of the face.
count = 0
while count < 20:
    (rval, im) = webcam.read()
    im = cv2.flip(im, 1, 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mini = cv2.resize(gray, (gray.shape[1] / size, gray.shape[0] / size))
    faces = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(mini)
    faces = sorted(faces, key=lambda x: x[3])
    if faces:
        face_i = faces[0]
        (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (im_width, im_height))
        pin=sorted([int(n[:n.find('.')]) for n in os.listdir(path)
               if n[0]!='.' ]+[0])[-1] + 1
        cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.png' % (path, pin), face_resize)
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(im, fn_name, (x - 10, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
            1,(0, 255, 0))
        count += 1
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', im)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Code for face recognition from the dataset

```
__author__ = 'ADMIN'
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
size = 4
fn_haar = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
fn_dir = 'att_faces'

# Part 1: Create fisherRecognizer
print('Training...')
# Create a list of images and a list of corresponding names
(images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)
for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(fn_dir):
    for subdir in dirs:
        names[id] = subdir
        subjectpath = os.path.join(fn_dir, subdir)
        for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath):
            path = subjectpath + '/' + filename
            lable = id
            images.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
            lables.append(int(lable))
        id += 1
(im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)

    # Create a Numpy array from the two lists above
(images, lables) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]]

# OpenCV trains a model from the images    
# NOTE FOR OpenCV2: remove '.face'
model = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
model.train(images, lables)

# Part 2: Use fisherRecognizer on camera stream
haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fn_haar)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    (rval, frame) = webcam.read()
    frame=cv2.flip(frame,1,0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mini = cv2.resize(gray, (gray.shape[1] / size, gray.shape[0] / size))
    faces = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(mini)
    for i in range(len(faces)):
        face_i = faces[i]
        (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (im_width, im_height))

    # Try to recognize the face
        prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

    # Write the name of recognized face
    # [1]
        cv2.putText(frame,
            '%s - %.0f' % (names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),
            (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Do you need save only name or also found face location?

Comment: Just the name of the detected face. thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't try this code but if I understood you correctly, you should create new dictionary (e.g. `found_faces = []`) or array before `while` and after `prediction` variable put `found_faces.append(names[prediction[0]])`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code. where i am not using any sql-server.
I am encoding images from the folder and it will show the recognized face with the name of the image saved. if the image is saved as .. abc.jpg. then it will detect the face during live streaming and show abc.jpg

here is my code :

```html
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition
import cv2
import os

# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

known_face_encodings=[]

known_face_names = []

user_appeared = []
root = "/home/erp-next/open cv/dataset/"
for filename in os.listdir(root):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg' or '.png'):
        try: 
            print(filename)
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            filter_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(path)
            filter_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(filter_image)
            known_face_encodings.append(filter_face_encoding[0])
            known_face_names.append(filename)
                        
        except:
            print("An exception occurred : " + filename )


#print(known_face_encodings)
print(known_face_names)

# Initialize some variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
# process_this_frame = True

def face():

    while True:

        process_this_frame = True

        # Grab a single frame of video
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

        # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

        k = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if k%256 == 27:
            # ESC pressed
            print("Escape hit, closing...")
            break

        # Only process every other frame of video to save time
        if process_this_frame:
            # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

            face_names = []
            for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                name = "Unknown"

                # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
                if True in matches:
                    first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                    name = known_face_names[first_match_index]
                    print(name)
                face_names.append(name)

        process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


        # Display the results
        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            # Draw a box around the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        # Display the resulting image
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release handle to the webcam
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


face()
```

i am also using face_recognition library to encode and detect face.

Thanks.